# calculations in data.table syntax

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to execute a self-join in `data.table`, to obtain the periods between time intervals.

Example data

```
active <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3), no=c(1,2,3,1,2,1), beg=as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01   01:10:00","2018-01-01 01:30:00","2018-01-01 01:50:00","2018-01-01 01:30:00","2018-01-01 01:50:00","2018-01-01 01:50:00")), end=as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 01:20:00","2018-01-01 01:40:00","2018-01-01 02:00:00","2018-01-01 01:40:00","2018-01-01 02:00:00","2018-01-01 02:00:00")))

> active
   id no                 beg                 end
1:  1  1 2018-01-01 01:10:00 2018-01-01 01:20:00
2:  1  2 2018-01-01 01:30:00 2018-01-01 01:40:00
3:  1  3 2018-01-01 01:50:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00
4:  2  1 2018-01-01 01:30:00 2018-01-01 01:40:00
5:  2  2 2018-01-01 01:50:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00
6:  3  1 2018-01-01 01:50:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00
```

What I want to reach is to get the inactive periods in between the active ones,

```
> res
   id no                ibeg                iend
1:  1  1 2018-01-01 01:20:00 2018-01-01 01:30:00
2:  1  2 2018-01-01 01:40:00 2018-01-01 01:50:00
3:  2  1 2018-01-01 01:40:00 2018-01-01 01:50:00
```

but my question is more general about the calculations in the syntax: When executing

```
res <- active[active, .(id=x.id, ibeg=i.end, iend=x.beg), on=.(no=(no-1), id=id)]
```

I match on `on=.(no=no-1)` but obtain an error message that `column [no-1] cannot be found`. I tried parentheses around `no-1` but to no avail. Are calculations banned from the `on=`argument or is there a trick?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: This is not possible yet, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639).

Comment: Thanks, Jaap, for clarifying. Also: how do you get the yellow background for the code output of your posts?

Comment: @bumblebee Did you even try what I suggested with `head` and `tail`? Updated version following the edit of your question: `active[ , .(ibeg = head(end, -1), iend = tail(beg, -1)), by = id]`.

Comment: Ah, now this works just as well and I also understand the intuition now. Thanks.

Comment: It worked before as well ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
inactive  = active[, .(no=no[-.N], ibeg=end[-.N], iend=beg[-1]), by=id]

#    id no                ibeg                iend
# 1:  1  1 2018-01-01 01:20:00 2018-01-01 01:30:00
# 2:  1  2 2018-01-01 01:40:00 2018-01-01 01:50:00
# 3:  2  1 2018-01-01 01:40:00 2018-01-01 01:50:00
```

Comment: excellent, thanks! I did see this also in a different solution but this was more generally about the calculations in the syntax. I wonder where these things are described in the documentation of `data.table`.

Comment: However, the solution gives error `Error in as.vector(x, "list") : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'`

Comment: @bumblebee this is generally the R api for doing these stuff, the only DT specific stuff is `.N` which means `nrow` in group, and `.()` alias for `list()`. All the rest is just do `j = .(...)` by group `by=id`.

Comment: don't understand that error - it does not give that on your example data, so it must be something about your own data that is different. btw did you try the edited anwer or the original one?

Comment: You were right, I had changed the example data in between. Works just fine.

Comment: @jangorecki I understand that subsetting using `[...] ` is base R (although I don't get the minus), but I find it hard to see which base-R functions work in data.table (such as this one) and which don't (such as my problem above).

Comment: the minus removes the specified elements

Comment: @bumblebee the thing is that `on` argument does not accept arbitrary R syntax, the second `[` argument, `j` do.